# git, share a clean code base to other users

Tags: git, github

We were using a private git repository hosted locally.

We had all the secret keys embeded in files.

We can't just remove files from the git history because the files include functional code other than secret key itself.

I came up with the following strategy although it doens't work.
I wonder if there are ways to make it work.

1. first remove all secret keys and modify the codes to use environment variables.
2. remove .git directory and reinitialize with `git init && git add .`
3. `git remote add origin [new-repo]` (we only want to share the clean state)
4. `git remote add upstream [original-repo]` (we still want to merge from original-repo)

It doesn't seem to work because git doesn't see any common commits between `new-repo` and `original-repo`.

Is there a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not share commit by only adding two remote to one local repository.

After added two remote repository, you should checkout branch from two remote individually,  those two branches should tracking remote branch, e.g.

> branch_a   ->  new_repo/branch_a
>
> branch_b   -> original_repo/branch_b

Now, you can merge/rebase two local branches branch_a & branch_b, and push them to remote.